# Show Stand-alone Application as popup/Dialog from App for Office application and communicate between AppForOffice and Custom application

Tags: office-js

I would like to show our application as Popup up when launched from App for Office in excel. Also, our application and App for Office should communicate with each other based on user actions.

Currently, we show our custom application in iFrame inside OfficeApp but now we would like to show a popup window to resolve the real estate issues.
With the current implementation, We have a usability issue as user need to move app and resize it each and every time when he tries using it as all fields are not displayed in the small area inside Office App.

I tried using Office Add-in Dialog API, thinking I can launch the custom app in the popup window but I did not find much help with it. 
It failed with errors and ended up in communication issues between custom
application Window and Office App.

Answer (score 0):

Note that task pane resize only works in Windows platform and hence not an ideal way to resolve size issue. The dialog window is the right way to go. Here is the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/dialog-boxes). Without details about specific error on dialog box, we can’t help further.